# Possible to get keyboard input from server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For testing purposes, I would like to check for keyboard input from the server (not the client) while processing a web request.

So, for example, if I'm holding down a key combination while it's processing a request then I could have the page show some additional section (or any number of things that I don't want to go in to detail about here; but not just looking to an answer for this one issue because obviously there are numerous other ways to solve that).

I do completely understand the ramifications of doing this. I totally get that it wouldn't just, in above example, show the extra section for me but for anyone who accesses the site while I hold the key combo down. But this is not something I would release to production; it's purely for testing purposes and only on my own dev machine.

I tried adding the System.Windows.Input reference but apparently it doesn't seem to appear for an asp.net mvc application. Is there another assembly with an api I could use for this, or would I maybe need to find an 3rd party assembly that has a keyboard hook?

Suggestions?

Comment: My two cents: I don't think this can be done, nor do I see any value in pursuing this.  What happens if you have a RDP user?  Multiple concurrent RDP users?  If you *could* do this, it would mean a keylogger would be easy to write on the server.  From a security standpoint, that's very bad.

Comment: @Amy You may be right. As for the RDP users, there wouldn't be any. As I mentioned this is just to make it easier for me to test some things locally on my own computer... not something to be deployed to a production server.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and stick a .json file in the project root.  Modify that file to trigger server-side changes instead of checking the keyboard.

Comment: @Amy Hm... not sure I follow you. Can you expound on that or point me to an article?

Comment: Create a file in the project root.  When your server wants to do something, it checks that file.  When you want to change its behavior, modify the file accordingly.  When you want its behavior to go back to normal, change it back.  This is a *far sight* better than wanting to check the keyboard, which I doubt is even possible due to security.

Comment: Oh I gotcha. I thought you were saying there was something special about having a json file in the root. You just meant to put one there and have code check it.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Its contents are completely up to you, and how that file changes system behavior is also completely up to you.  Maybe the mere *existence* of the file, instead of its content, is all you need to trigger a change of behavior.  You can also do this with the configuration file, but modifying the `web.config` typically causes the app pool to recycle, which is beyond the scope of what you're requesting.

Comment: Yeah... I was really wanting something even more convenient though. Checking for keyboard input in winforms apps is incredibly simple and convenient... for this I either have to write a lot of extra code for any new thing I want to try to test or else write a tiny framework of sorts to make it simple to use. :/

Comment: Well you could host your application inside a Winforms application.  Re-architecting your server to do something like this is hardly what I would call convenient though.  I've already stated that I don't think this is worth pursuing, so good luck to you I guess.